# Data fetch during spring batch step execution

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch job. Whose reader reads some records from DB by some complex sql. Now for every record i received from DB, i have to hit one more table to fetch some attributes. Note :- I can't join this table sql in reader step. So these fetched attributes along with data from existing record i need to write down to file. Can this done with Spring batch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible using an item processor that would fetch additional data for each item. This is a common pattern know as the "driving query pattern" and is described in the [Common Batch Patterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders) section.

However, this pattern is not the best in terms of performance (for huge data sets) as you will have an additional query for each item (N+1 query issue) but it is useful and efficient for most use cases with medium/small data sets.

Comment: Yeah, that was my next question. For every record we will be having a DB fetch transaction. It would definitely be costly.